# Find the blog post associated with a comment programmatically

Tags: search-results, blog

I'm working on a custom webpart that can search through all comments made on a blog subsite and return the posts that are associated with those comments (not the comments themselves) and match the search terms.  I have found that the comments list exists on the subsite itself (at the same level as the posts list) instead of underneath posts and am having a hard time getting to the post that a comment was associated with once I find a comment that matches my search criteria.  I've looked through a comment's properties in Visual Studio for a while now and can't seem to find anything yet but there has to be something since SharePoint knows which comments are associated with which posts.  Has anyone ran into this issue before and can shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Comments list has a lookup column to the Posts lists called Post Title. So in your web part, you'd want to be querying the Comment list for the particular post and you'll get all the associated Comments.